# How to get mp4 url on source page?

Tags: php, regex, string, file-get-contents, preg-match-all

My page source have this html (js):

```
<script>
playlist.sources.push({
    label: "480p",
    source: "//zingtv-video-14.zadn.vn/Video480/2016/0418/7c/1f1fd73f7432d7524cb43b57da35d6df.mp4?authen=exp=1559094603~acl=1f1fd73f7432d7524cb43b57da35d6df~hmac=01da84812b2ef7d43e55be79fa3ef56e",
    index: 1
});</script>
```

I want to get:

```
//zingtv-video-14.zadn.vn/Video480/2016/0418/7c/1f1fd73f7432d7524cb43b57da35d6df.mp4?authen=exp=1559094603~acl=1f1fd73f7432d7524cb43b57da35d6df~hmac=01da84812b2ef7d43e55be79fa3ef56e
```

My code :

```
<?php
  // Check if the URL parameter for our proxy is set.
  if (!empty($_GET['url'])) {
    if (filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
      $grabs = file_get_contents("{$_GET['url']}");


      $grab = json_decode($grabs, true);
// I don't know what to do next

      echo "{$video}" />";
    } else {
      echo "Given URL is not valid.";
    }
  } else {
    echo "You need to specify the URL.";
  }
?>
```

and show in the content page.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Oh sorry, i edited my post , i want to get //zingtv-video-14.zadn.vn/Video480/2016/0418/7c/1f1fd73f7432d7524cb43b57da35d6df.mp4?authen=exp=1559094603~acl=1f1fd73f7432d7524cb43b57da35d6df~hmac=01da84812b2ef7d43e55be79fa3ef56e from html source with php and i need php code, if you know please give for me source

Comment: Please show what you have tried. `i need php code` is not how SO is meant to work. We're here to help you with your coding issues.

Comment: I have updated the article, I don't know what to do with the $video variable so I can get that code

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can try using `preg_match_all` with a simple expression:

```
source: "(.+)",
```

where our desired output is saved in a capturing group `$1`.

#### Test

```
$re = '/source: "(.+)",/m';
$str = '<script>
playlist.sources.push({
    label: "480p",
    source: "//zingtv-video-14.zadn.vn/Video480/2016/0418/7c/1f1fd73f7432d7524cb43b57da35d6df.mp4?authen=exp=1559094603~acl=1f1fd73f7432d7524cb43b57da35d6df~hmac=01da84812b2ef7d43e55be79fa3ef56e",
    index: 1
});</script>';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches[0][1]);
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/V9fHcA/1/)

---

I'm not quite sure if this `file_get_content` would work:

```
$str = file_get_contents('https://tv.zing.vn/video/id/IWZBFE8U.html?t=388');
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
var_dump($str);
```

Comment: Please help me again, I need to get the .mp4 snippet from this page, I tried using loadHTMLFile and use your code but can't get it : https://tv.zing.vn/video/id/IWZBFE8U.html?t=388

Comment: @VõHữuNhân Emma has answered your question. How to retrieve an mp4 file is not on topic for this question. You might hit memory limits, TOS violations, etc. Retrieving a string has been answered. Also please go through your other questions and if others have been answered accepted those answers.

Comment: @Emma I might updated the answer to replace `.+",` and the `m` with `[^"]+?"`. This assumes that the encapsulation is consistent. The trailing comma could be optional though because the last element won't need that.

Comment: Thank you, Emma for helping me, thanks user3783243, I will consider

Comment: @Emma I'm not sure what is meant by `I need to get the .mp4 snippet` to me it was retrieving part of a video. The `source` is also an mp4 file so I presumed they wanted that. I'm not familiar with `zing.vn` nor `zadn.vn` and how they relate.